# When x = 10³⁰, y = -10³⁰ and z = 1, why do (x+y)+z and x+(y+z) differ?

Tags: math, floating-point

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) makes the following claim:

> Due to roundoff errors, the associative laws of algebra do not necessarily hold for floating-point numbers. For example, the expression (x+y)+z has a totally different answer than x+(y+z) when x = 10<sup>30</sup>, y = -10<sup>30</sup> and z = 1 (it is 1 in the former case, 0 in the latter).

How does one reach the conclusion in their example? That is, that (x+y)+z=1 and x+(y+z)=0?

I am aware of the associative laws of algebra, but I do not see the issue in this case. To my mind, both x and y will overflow and therefore both have an integer value that is incorrect but nonetheless in range. As x and y will then be integers, they should add as if associativity applies.

Comment: Have you tried it out? (Including printing the intermediate values)

Comment: Also, what significance do you attach to the fact that the operands  are integers? Do you understand the distinction between a variable being a floating point-typed variable holding an integer, and a variable being an integer type?

Comment: @Sneftel Integers don't have roundoff errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round off error, and other aspects of floating point arithmetic, apply to floating point arithmetic as a whole. While some of the values that a floating point variable can store are integers (in the sense that they are whole numbers), they are not integer-typed. A floating point variable cannot store arbitrarily large integers, any more than an integer variable can. And while wraparound integer arithmetic will make `(a+b)-a=b` for any unsigned integer-typed a and b, the same is not true for floating point arithmetic. The overflow rules are different.

Answer (score 0):

> When x = 10^(30), y = -10^(30) and z = 1, why do (x+y)+z and x+(y+z) differ?

In addition to [@Sneftel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65728098/2410359) answer, note the results do not *have* to differ either.

Even when the floating point type of the operands has insufficient precession to encode the sum 1 + 10<sup>30</sup> exactly, like [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), some languages, like C, allow intermediate calculations to compute using higher precision (like maybe `long double` as [binary128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)) leading to a common sum  of -1.